# Android put button numbers into list which text is in string list

Tags: java, android

I have buttons which contain some random character as their text. I need to exclude the buttons that contains characters from the `ArrayList`.

Or, a better explanation, I have characters `a, s, d, a` in my ArrayList and I need the numbers of the buttons that have `a`, `s`, `d` or `a` in their text.

My code is below. Whats wrong with it?

**EDIT:** Expected output is `buttonNumbers[]` with numbers of butons. For now, every value of this array == 1.

```
public void adsf() {
    ArrayList<String> characters = new ArrayList<String>();
    characters.addAll(spreadToCharacters(getWord(getActualNumber())));

    Button [] but = new Button[26];
    but[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    but[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    but[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    but[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    but[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    but[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);
    but[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);
    but[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);
    but[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    but[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    but[10] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b11);
    but[11] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b12);
    but[12] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b13);
    but[13] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b14);
    but[14] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b15);
    but[15] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b16);
    but[16] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b17);
    but[17] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b18);
    but[18] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b19);
    but[19] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b20);
    but[20] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b21);
    but[21] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b22);
    but[22] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b23);
    but[23] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b24);
    but[24] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b25);
    but[25] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b26);

    int[] buttonNumbers = new int[characters.size()];
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<but.length; i++) {
        for(int o = 0; o < characters.size(); o++) {
            if(but[i].getText().equals(characters.get(o))) {
                for(int z = 0; z < buttonNumbers.length; z++) {
                    if(i != buttonNumbers[z]) {
                        buttonNumbers[j] = i;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual output of this code? How does it differ from the desired output? This should be clearly stated in the question. "It don't works" isn't a clear statement of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uTry the `contains` method:

```
int[] buttonNumbers = new int[characters.size()];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < but.length; i++){
    for (String s : characters){
        if (but.getText().contains(s)){
            buttonNumbers[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

But if you want to check for duplicates, I would let buttonNumbers be a `List`:

```
    List<Integer> buttonNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < but.length; i++){
        for (String s : characters){
            if (but.getText().contains(s) && !buttonNumbers.contains(i)){
                buttonNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```